# Bootstrap on Angular 7 getting error as 'Property collapse does not exist on type `JQuery<HTMLElement>`

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, angular7

I am trying to close the `collapse` panel on click outside of the drop down. i try with following code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
declare var $:JQueryStatic;
import { State } from "./../../state/app.state";
import * as fromSetupConfig from "./../../setup-config/state/setup-config.reducer";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private store:Store<State>) { }

    currentName:string;

    ngOnInit() {

        this.store.pipe(select(fromSetupConfig.getCurrentName)).subscribe(newName => {
            this.currentName = newName
        });

        $(document).click(function(e) {
            if (!$(e.target).is('.panel-body')) {
                $('.collapse').collapse('hide');      //throws error  
            }
        });

    }

}
```

But getting error as error: `Property collapse does not exist on type`JQuery` - how to fix this?

[image: error]

Comment: Have you tried `document.querySelectorAll('.collapse').collapse('hide');` - since the error is basically saying that the jQuery return does not have the collapse method (which is part of the bootstrap methods, no jquery)

Comment: so what is the correct way to integrate the Boostrap with jquery in angular? can't we?

Comment: I have never tried, so I wouldn't be able to answer that. But the error seems to point to the fact the the jquery return array does not have the collapse method - so the logical solution would be to select the element in the vanilla method - or possibly use the single element selector: `$('.collapse').get(0).collapse('hide')`

Comment: Can you let me know if either is the working solution, so I can post it as the answer :-)

Comment: @asimovwasright - nope same issue. getting underlined with `collapse` again!!

Comment: In that case, it would appear that the bootstrap library is not initialised. I don't know enough about Angular environments to debug that, sorry.

Comment: bro you cant assign bootstrap predefined jquery functions to angular, for that you have 2 options. 1st use ng-bootstrap or 2nd way is called `jugad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having here is because of the typescript compiler. To circumvent that, you could initialize the collapse and other elements in a basic JS file. You will need to import this file so create it either in the assets folder (and link it in your `index.html`) or in another location and mention it in the `scripts` part of your `angular.json`.

To initialize collapse, the content of this JS file would be :

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.panel-body')) {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');      //throws error  
    }
});
```

This would initialize all Jquery functions, when the document gets ready.

If you want to do that at a specific moment in the Angular flow, wrap the call in a function like so :

```
function collapse() {
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.panel-body')) {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');      //throws error  
    }
  });
}
```

To call it in a Typescript file, you'll need to first declare the function. For example, to initialize the jquery functions in `ngOnInit()` :

```
declare function collapse();
ngOnInit() {
  collapse();
}
```

This way you won't need to `import 'bootstrap';` anywhere and so you won't break your other components.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who does not want that type of a fix, the clean way would be installing the `@types/bootstrap` package by running `npm install @types/bootstrap` and importing bootstrap afterwards using `import 'bootstrap'`. Thats at least what helped me and its also cleaner that adding a function outside of typescript and telling typescript afterwards, that there is such a function and it just has to believe me.

Also `declare var $:JQueryStatic` is just a way of telling typescript to trust me and not actually check if its true, that $ is JQuery, the clean way here would be something like `import * as $ from 'jquery';`.

Greatings DragonSkills99